# why composer fail during running the server?

Tags: symfony, composer-php

The autoloader expected class "AppBundle\Resources\config\routing" to be de
  fined in file "C:\xampp\htdocs\fp\vendor\composer/../../src/AppBundle\Resou
  rces\config\routing.php". The file was found but the class was not in it, t
  he class name or namespace probably has a typo in C:\xampp\htdocs\fp\app/co
  nfig\services.yml (which is being imported from "C:\xampp\htdocs\fp\app/con
  fig\config.yml").

Comment: You probably added namespace to routing file?

Add your routing.php here.

Comment: Why do you think that this behaviour is related to composer? What does `app/config/services.yml` contain?

Comment: Nothing to do with composer.  The autowire portion of Symfony thinks routing.php should be a class which of course it is not.  Add AppBundle\Resources to the exclude section in services.yaml or disable autowire.